# Create a directory and get the handle by issuing one IRP

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, filesystems, ntfs

When we create a file by CreateFile, the file created and we get the handle.
But CreateDirectory doesn't return directory's handle.

I'd like to also get the handle when I create a directory.
I want to handle this by issuing only one I/O request packet.

So, 'Do CreateDirectory, then CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS.' won't be an answer.
It will issue two Irps to file system.

Is there an Api I can use in Usermode(Win32 Api)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NT can do this, but Win32 doesn't expose it.  You need to use NT APIs for this.  [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically.  It should follow the same parameters of [ZwCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's an illustrative example (hacked up in a hurry inside a web form -- YMMV):

```
HANDLE
CreateDirectoryAndGetHandle(PWSTR pszFileName)
{
    NTSTATUS Status;
    UNICODE_STRING FileName;
    HANDLE DirectoryHandle;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatus;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&FileName, pszFileName);
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAtributes, &FileName, 0, NULL, NULL);

    Status = NtCreateFile(&DirectoryHandle,
                          GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                          &ObjectAttributes,
                          &IoStatus,
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                          FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                          FILE_CREATE,
                          FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE,
                          NULL,
                          0);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
       return DirectoryHandle;
    }
    else
    {
       SetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(Status));
       return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Some things to note...

- NT paths have slightly different conventions than Win32 paths...  You might have to sanitize the path.
- When talking about `HANDLE`s, NT APIs generally deal with `NULL` rather than `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.
- I didn't do it here, but by changing the `InitializeObjectAttributes` call you can do interesting things, like do a create relative to another directory handle.  Of course all the flags I've put in here you might also want to change.  Consult documentation and/or the web for best results.

Comment: +1 This is the correct approach, but be weary: As the [documentation mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432200.aspx), this function is "subject to change from one release of Windows to the next and possibly even between service packs for each release." At the very least, you should always access these functions through dynamic run-time links, in case it has been changed or removed.

Comment: `CreateFile` actually can create a directory. Set the disposition to `CREATE_NEW` and the flags to `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`. Since this isn't documented, it probably isn't implemented in ReactOS and Wine. Note that if you're in a scripting environment such as Python, make sure to use the correct value of `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` from the headers (0x01000000). The value listed on MSDN has always been wrong.

Comment: For NTFS you can also create the `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` attribute. Here's a silly version of `mkdir dirname` in a command prompt: `type nul > dirname::$INDEX_ALLOCATION`. Of course it doesn't work on a FAT32 drive.